# Pig Latin: how to try-catch for errors regarding casting?

Tags: apache-pig

Let's say I have a structured data in Pig named "my_great_data" and it has the following fields: "a_field", "b_field" and "c_field".

I want to write a filter statement that filters in all "rows" in "my_great_data" that their "a_field" can be casted to long data type.

Something like:

```
my_great_data_output = filter my_great_data BY (a_field can be casted to long);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple Python UDF to do the casting and return a null if it's not possible. You can then use `IS NOT NULL` in a filter to remove the records that failed to cast.

Something like:

```
from pig_util import outputSchema

@outputSchema("cast_value:long")
def castToLong(num):
    if num is None:
        return None
    try:
        # Should handle strings with a decimal point
        # Use long(num) if these should not be cast.
        r = long(float(num))
        return r
    except:
        return None
```